# Drawable Icon and Label Padding Issue

Tags: xamarin, material-design, material-ui

[image: This is The View]

I want Give paddingtop to Floating Label and set The DrawableRight Icon In Center.

```xml
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/input_layout_password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    android:theme="@style/TextLabel"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/CustomBackGround"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/DatePicker"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="ok"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:hint="Select Date"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/calendar_month"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="15"
        android:textColor="#FF808080"/>
 </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: `I want to Give paddingtop to Floating Label`- I do not think this possible, `and set The DrawableRight Icon In Center.` center of what?

Comment: Yes it is possible

Comment: Drawable icon in center of Edit Text

Comment: I found it's hard to center the image under TextInputLayout, did you achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm finding it hard to work out what you asking for but you can set the Drawable to: Botton, End Left, Right, Start, Top

I add 5dp padding to the image and added them for all options, like so:

```xml
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/input_layout_password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    android:theme="@style/TextLabel"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/CustomBackGround"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/DatePicker"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="ok"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:hint="Select Date"

        android:drawableBottom="@drawable/calendar_month"
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/calendar_month"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/calendar_month"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/calendar_month"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/calendar_month"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/calendar_month"

        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="15"
        android:textColor="#FF808080"/>
 </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: As i post image  .I have set calendar icon inside the Edit Text.The issue is The Calendar is not in the center of Right Side.So I want The icon Should be in Center of Edit Text. Hope So you Get It Now

Comment: Yes Brother I also Done it...i was not found the solution for center icon ...But you can   
Adjust little bit by using Padding